# How to logout Azure from swa-cli?

Tags: azure-static-web-app, swa-cli

Azure SWA offer `swa login` command. What if I want to **logout** Azure account. What can I do? There is no `swa logout` command by default.

Answer (score 1):

It because I use Windows 10. Here are the commands we need to clear credentials.

Find all credential created by `swa-cli`

```
cmdkey.exe /list | findstr swa-cli
```

Clear all credential created by `swa-cli`

```
cmdkey.exe /list | findstr swa-cli | ForEach-Object {
  cmdkey /delete:$($_.Split(' ')[5])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.1.4, there's a `--clear-credentials` command-line [option](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/docs/cli/swa-login/#options):

```bash
$ npx @azure/static-web-apps-cli login --help

Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.1.4)

Usage: swa login [options]

login into Azure

Options:
  -S, --subscription-id <subscriptionId>  Azure subscription ID used by this project (default: "...")
  -R, --resource-group <resourceGroup>    Azure resource group used by this project
  -T, --tenant-id <tenantId>              Azure tenant ID (default: "...")
  -C, --client-id <clientId>              Azure client ID
  -CS, --client-secret <clientSecret>     Azure client secret
  -n, --app-name <appName>                Azure Static Web App application name
           
  -CC, --clear-credentials                clear persisted credentials before login (default: false)
```

So you could run:

```
npx @azure/static-web-apps-cli login --clear-credentials
```

or:

```
npx @azure/static-web-apps-cli login -CC
```